# Sensing an actuator using vision

Tags: control, computer-vision

I am looking forward for a method to sense in real time, using computer vision for a control application.

For this I am unsure of which is the right platform . I am well versed with MATLAB, but I am wondering if it will be able to do the image processing in real time or not.

If there are other platforms which are much quicker, you can please recommend me.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* qwerty123, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: If you are ever unsure about a Matlab toolbox, just call Mathworks and ask for a trial. I've used several trials in the past and, as I recall, the trial periods are pretty generous - I believe about 30 days. Speed is all relative to what you're trying to do but, in general, the fastest programs run in C++.

Answer (score 2):

The branch of science that is binding vision and control is called visual servoying. You can find visp written in cpp or matlab implementations. Check also if visp is having a matlab bridge/api. If you have a professional robot (not a diy one ) i think ROS + visp will be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB is a very powerful platform for doing such applications. I recommend you using it. You can get your images using a USB camera, implement whatever functions to your captured images and then plot your results in a GUI charts or tabs.

Other software you can use is LabVIEW of NI, but you have to know how to use a function block diagram programming language.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work on matlab with vision,but if you want another choice you can always use c++/in visual studio with opencv libraries 
Or java in eclipse,but opencv function for c++ are easier and there are much more tutorials